# Saving data on android, that cant be removed

Tags: android, save

There is any possibility to save data by android app, that user are not able to remove, except by uninstall the app.

Data stay save even if user clear app data. 
Can I use to this preferences?

Comment: SharedPreferences will be cleared when the user clears app data. Not sure about files, try them.

Comment: I don't know much about android development, but I assume it's much more lenient than iOS development. In this case, perhaps you can look into storing the data inside the app package itself (assuming it allows you to do this).

Also, why do you want this? You might want to rethink what your doing here, because users generally like to be able to control their data.

Comment: I've got some ranking and user can rate item without being login. So I need to save id of each item that user rate.

Comment: Is it possible to create the file in assets and edit it? Maybe this will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is any possibility to save data by android app, that user are not able to remove, except by uninstall the app.

Fortunately, this is not possible. Your users own their devices, not you.